# How do create organized groups using arrays?

Tags: java, arrays

I am in another hole, I need to be able to print a text file containing populations of cities through the use of an array as groups. These groups include: NA (no population listed), 5000-7499, 7500-9999, and 10,000-infinity. the populations are stored in a text file listed as shown below. I also have the current code I'm using to print the Populations from greatest to least not including grouping the Na's out.

In the end I need a program that can organize a text file into groups with the use of arrays. However, I still have no clue how to work arrays. Any help would be greatly appreciated. And if I wasn't clear about anything or something doesn't make sense please feel free to ask questions... I'm still very new to programming. Thank You!!!

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Population {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
// TODO code application logic here

// // read KeyWestTemp.txt

// create token1
String token1 = "";


// create Scanner inFile1
Scanner inFile1 = new Scanner(new File("Populationtxt")).useDelimiter(",\\s*");

// Original answer used LinkedList, but probably preferable to use ArrayList in most cases
// List<String> temps = new LinkedList<String>();
List<String> temps = new ArrayList<String>();

// while loop
while (inFile1.hasNext()) {
  // find next line
  token1 = inFile1.next();
  temps.add(token1);
}
inFile1.close();

String[] tempsArray = temps.toArray(new String[0]);

for (String s : tempsArray) {
  System.out.println(s);


  }
  }
  }
```

Here is the information listed in the text file:

```
Philadelphia city:, 1526006

Pittsburgh city:,       305704

Harrisburg city:,       49528

Altoona city:,          46320

State College borough:, 42034

Monroeville municipality:, NA

Johnstown city:,        20978

Murrysville municipality:,20079

McKeesport city:,   NA

Greensburg city:,           14892

Indiana borough:,         13975

Washington city:,         13663

Meadville city:, NA

New Kensington city:,   13116

St. Marys city:,        13070

Lower Burrell city:,    11761

Munhall borough:,   NA

Jefferson Hills borough:,   10619

Waynesboro borough:,    10568

Oil City city:,         10557

Uniontown city:,        10372

Lock Haven city:,       9772

Jeannette city:,        9654

Beaver Falls city:, NA

Swissvale borough:, 8983

Mechanicsburg borough:, 8981

Carbondale city:,   NA

Latrobe city:,          8338

Grove City borough:,    8322

Pleasant Hills borough:,    8268

White Oak borough:, NA

DuBois city:,           7794

Monessen city:,         7720

Connellsville city:,    7637

Gettysburg borough:,    7620

California borough:,    6795

Somerset borough:,  6277

Clearfield borough:,    NA

McKees Rocks borough:,  6104

Punxsutawney borough:,  5962

Duquesne city:,         5565

Shippensburg borough:,  5492

Fox Chapel borough:,    5388

Turtle Creek borough:,  5349

Clarion borough:,         5276

Vandergrift borough:,   NA

Westmont borough:,  5181

Arnold city:,   NA

Kutztown borough:,  5012
```

Comment: Use a `Map<Population, List<Location>>` where Population would be a population bracket as the key.

Comment: alright i can try that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To solve this you will have to sort your data. I am going to assume you don't want to reorder the text file but it is not that hard to add in. So what you can do to sort the data is find a simple algorithm. If you have time I recommend going into detail on bigger and more complex sorting algorithms but for starting you can use a simple algorithm. What you need to do is grab the number or character and find the value. Then add it to an array and finally sort all of the data in the arrays.
Character.isDigit(string); Then if it is true add it to the array for a number. After that, you can use a simple sorting algorithm like bubble sort to move the numbers into order then print out the list completed in a for loop with the city name in a separate array.

Comment: Thank you for all the info, ill give those algorithms a look. I really appreciate the help!

Comment: @tvalentine I am just happy I could help!